# Why only in first install of application the registrationManager is send in Marketing Cloud SDK Android?

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, sdk

Hi in the past of my app we were using phone number as ContactKey but in February this changes to a personal UUID generated and stored in database.

This is an example like with the phone number

```
MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
        val registrationManager = sdk.registrationManager

        registrationManager.edit().run {
            setContactKey(phoneNumber)
            setAttribute("channel", "app")
            commit()
        }
    }
```

And this is the new code

```
MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                val registrationManager = sdk.registrationManager

                registrationManager.edit().run {
                    setContactKey(accountId)
                    setAttribute("channel", "app")
                    commit()
                }
            }
```

This code executes in application open (when the user is already login) or when the user is just going to login, but **the event for registration is only send when the user uninstall the application and reinstall and login or in the first install**, and for all the users whose doesn't do this is not updating the ContactKey and they still have the phoneNumber as ContactKey, but my question is **Why only in first install of application the registration is send?**

[image]

I don't want the users have to uninstall and reinstall to update the ContactKey so I don't know if there is other way to do this or this is how the SDK working

Comment: What version of the SDK? Also, there are no issues in the SDK. You should look at whether or not your code is being executed. Billions (yes, with a B) of contacts update their registration all the time.

Comment: Version com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:7.4.1, this is mi sdk version, my code is always excecuting I debug and always executes that code but only in first installation the registration is sending, and I don't know why

Comment: That version of the SDK has been GA for a very long time and no other customers are experiencing this issue. Please open a support case.